# passing msqli to a function - can't suss out why it's not working

Tags: sql, mysqli

I've searched high and low for an answer on this, but I'm either missing something, or I just can't find anything in this context.

Background - trying to avoid spaghetti frenzy with a little casual project I'm starting;  part of this will involve mainly just calls to a mysql database, displaying table content and so on.  Simply put, like a CRM I guess.

I may be way off base here, but I want to be able to create my sql calls as functions, which will help if/when I tweak and tune, as well as creating a cleaner code for what I'm looking to do.

So, without further ado, I have this as a demomstration:

```
echo "<table>";
selectall('actions','content',$mysqli);
echo "</table><br><br>";
```

What this does is show all rows from my table of 'actions.  "content" is just an example field name I'm passing through that I want to display, as it is the main human-relevant field name in that table.  I'm also passing $mysqli through here for my function db call.

My function looks like this:

```
function selectall($s_table,$s_content,$mysqli){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $s_table;
    $resource = $mysqli->query($query);
                if ( !$resource ) throw new Exception($db->error);
                while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    echo "<tr><td>{$row[$s_content]}</td></tr>";
                }
    $resource->free();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

However.... it doesn't work, and it seems to throw a wobbly saying:

```
Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
```

This points to the action within the line $resource = $mysqli->query($query);

I know the function and everything is ok, as if I restate and declare $mysqli within the first line of the function, like so...

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(username password and so on in here);
```

... it works spot on.

$mysqli exists and works within the same code that is passing the variable within the function too.

This is early stages, so by shuffling the code around trying to poke the $mysqli pass into life I have perhaps made the code a little messier that intended, so try not to worry too much about that.

Anyone any ideas why it doesn't like this?

Comment: As an update, I've found that if I declare $msqli beforehand, it also works..



    `$mysqli = new mysqli('connection info');
    echo "<table>";
    selectall('actions','content',$mysqli);
    echo "</table><br><br>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D'oh...

I had a

```
$mysqli->close();
```

in the lines above. Solved myself.

For reference, this is my function:

```
function selectall($s_table,$s_field,$mysqli){

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);}
$s_table = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z_]/', '', $s_table); // Cleans up the table name variable
$s_field = preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z_]/', '', $s_field); // Cleans up the field name variable
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $s_table;  // Adds passed table name to the select all
$resource = $mysqli->query($query);

if ( !$resource ) throw new Exception($db->error);

while ( $row = $resource->fetch_assoc() ) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$row[$s_field]}</td></tr>"; // Content for each row of the select all
    }
$resource->free();
$mysqli->close();
}
```

As you can see, I've also tried to protect the variables that enter the function.

This can be called via:

```
selectall('actions','content',$mysqli);
```

In this context, I want to view all the entries in the 'actions' table by the field name 'content'. This function, with some code above and below for a table, will create a new row for each entry.

I'll probably evolve a few, already created on that includes a delete button at the end of the line which is 'selectalldel'.

Open to comments on whether this actually is worthwhile, but thought I'd post up my corrected stupidity in case anyone finds this useful.

Comment: This function is quite useless. Soon you will learn that you never need a query like select * from table

Comment: That's a defeatist attitude.  Development is, by the very nature of its name, is about taking something and improving upon it.  The only difference between your judgement, and disproving it, is passing an additional variable to define the fields to be drawn (which I've already done).

Comment: Ah, no problem. you will learn that a query like select foo,bar from table is useless as well.

Comment: A development, indeed, stands for the improvement. Your function, in fact, diminishes the precious language of sql to a state of a silly text file

Comment: I'm not sure if you intend to make passive aggressive statements for your own amusement, or a strange way of helping?
I'm attempting to think out of the box in producing clean code with common db calls produced through functions, instead of repetitive SQL strings.